# ValueError using of np.load

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

hi i have one main dataset and based the some conditions extract the train and test dataset from it, when i want to import training dataset i get this error

"ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
11
12 train = pd.read_csv("/content/path (1).csv")
---> 13 X_train = np.load(train + "/X_220_1020.npy", allow_pickle=True, encoding='latin1')
14 Y_train = np.load(train + "/Y.npy", allow_pickle=True, encoding='latin1')
15 print("X_train size:", X_train.shape)

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numexpr/necompiler.py in getType(a)
702         return bytes
703     if kind == 'U':
--> 704         raise ValueError('NumExpr 2 does not support Unicode as a dtype.')
705     raise ValueError("unknown type %s" % a.dtype.name)
706

ValueError: NumExpr 2 does not support Unicode as a dtype.."

this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, StratifiedKFold, train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, accuracy_score, balanced_accuracy_score, f1_score, matthews_corrcoef, classification_report, make_scorer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from xlwt import Workbook
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import unique_labels

df = pd.read_csv("/content/CPM.csv",index_col=0) #read the main CPM dataset(67k × 719 )
v = df.transpose() # (719 × 67k)


# the path pf data sets that we want extract from main
training=  pd.read_excel("/content/train.test.xlsx", sheet_name="train")
testing = pd.read_excel("/content/train.test.xlsx", sheet_name="test")
feature_space="/content/FEATURE_SPACES.xlsx"


#the list of feature space name 
name=["FEATURE_SPACE1", "FEATURE_SPACE2","FEATURE_SPACE3(LIMMA)","FEATURE_SPACE4(LIMMA)", "FEATURE_SPACE5", "FEATURE_SPACE6", "FEATURE_SPACE7""FEATURE_SPACE9"]


#if we want to choose from feature spaces excel file
def extract2(path, sheet_name, dataset):
  df1 = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=sheet_name) # path of subdatset 
  list_of= df1['isoform'].values.tolist()  #exatrct the list of isoforms names as list
  data = v[np.intersect1d(v.columns, list_of)]  # find the mutual isoform between main datset and subdatset 
  data.reset_index(inplace=True)
  data.rename(columns={ data.columns[0]: "sample_id" }, inplace = True)
  x = dataset['sample_id'].values.tolist()
  data1= data.loc[data['sample_id'].isin(x)]
  b = data1.to_csv("path.csv", index=False) # save as csv file 


c = extract2(feature_space, name[1], training)  # for example wants to exatrct feature space1
train = pd.read_csv("/content/path.csv")
X_train = np.load(train + "/X_220_1020.npy", , allow_pickle=True)
Y_train = np.load(train + "/Y.npy" , allow_pickle=True)
print("X_train size:", X_train.shape)
```

Comment: Please paste the entire error trace, including the specific line where the error arises.

Comment: The ValueError looks like it's being raised from [this line in `numexpr`](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/f9cd0666ee38d763574d9b8c56e78de1f2995fe0/numexpr/necompiler.py#L704), but the code posted here does not involve `numexpr`. This looks like it's an error with how the data in `X_220_1020.npy` and `Y.npy` were produced.

Comment: @jhso i updated the question and add he entire error trace